# -[WKSyntheticTapGestureRecognizer setState:] crash

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access

We have encountered the crash : -[WKSyntheticTapGestureRecognizer setState:]  in our app.I am also attaching crash report for the reference:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1540 objc_msgSend + 32
1  WebKit                         0x4a6bd8 -[WKSyntheticTapGestureRecognizer setState:] + 100
2  UIKitCore                      0x2bb320 -[UITapRecognizer tooSlow:] + 76
3  Foundation                     0x365fc __NSFireDelayedPerform + 460
4  CoreFoundation                 0xae318 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
5  CoreFoundation                 0x32cf0 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1076
6  CoreFoundation                 0x2d4ec __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 328
7  CoreFoundation                 0xbd08 __CFRunLoopRun + 1944
8  CoreFoundation                 0x1f468 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
9  GraphicsServices               0x138c GSEventRunModal + 164
10 UIKitCore                      0x51a088 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100
11 UIKitCore                      0x298958 UIApplicationMain + 2092
12 Adoddle Field Plus             0x1238f0 main + 17 (main.mm:17)
13 ???                            0x10817daa4 (Missing)
```

Comment: `objc_msgSend` frequently means that the object you're sending the message to has already been released.  Do you see a console error message as well?  ...or a message in the header of the crash report?

Answer (score 0):

`KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000010`

Like WKSyntheticTapGesturestabilizer has been released and is still accessing its member variables